# the node-hid library won’t work in my Electron 24 app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron, hid

Im making my first Electron app. With the press of a button i should be able to see all the connected devices in my computer, but my app won’t render and I only get errors like this:

> Error: Dynamic require of "os" is not supported
> at chunk-OROXOI2D.js?v=f95a2a6e:10:9
> at node_modules/.vite-electron-renderer/os.mjs (os.mjs:1:50)
> at __init (chunk-OROXOI2D.js?v=f95a2a6e:13:56)
> at node_modules/node-hid/nodehid.js (nodehid.js:2:10)
> at __require2 (chunk-OROXOI2D.js?v=f95a2a6e:16:50)
> at nodehid.js:133:25

I've tried lots of things, such as building the function to get the data in the app.tsx file, but it wont work.
The only time i got it to work was when i executed the script with the `node nameofthescript.js` command.
I've also tried to rebuild the project with [electron-rebuild](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-rebuild) but it just changes my module type from EcmaScript to CommonJS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your library only works on node environment, which is not available in renderer process, you can create a function and execute it in main process then send the result to renderer process, which is everything included in your main.tsx, like this:

**main.ts**

```
 app.whenReady().then(() => {
  const connectedDevices = //call your lib
  const window = createWindow()
  window.webContent.send('connected-devices',connectedDevices)


  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})
```

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-args

*Extra*

Also the package need to be install in your app/package.json if you are using the 2 package.json structure